# Spark - tsv file read as empty

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, formatting

I have a .csv file that uses "\t" as a delimiter which I am trying to read as:

```
DF =  sqlc.read.format('csv').option('header', 'true').option('delimiter', '\t').load('file.csv')
```

Some of the header column names as well as data values do contain spaces, but never tabs. Header of this file is read correctly into the header of the DF, but no data is read into the DataFrame. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is changing the delimiter in the file to commas a viable option?

Comment: definitely viable, but suboptimal

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a `SparkSession` API?

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
# spark_context = spark.sparkContext
csv = spark.read.csv(csv_path, sep="\t")
csv.show()
```

The documentation is here: 
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=csv#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv

Comment: Doesn't help. Currently I am using SparkContext, but it seems the SparkSession is newer, better approach so thanks for that.

Comment: is there a reason you don't use sparksession? It should be as easy as copying that code in with a proper import... You can always access the spark context from the spark session object

Comment: No, I just wasn't aware of existence of SparkSession.

Comment: ok consider using SparkSession in order to achieve the ends you want (I'll update the code snippet to include the import)